# How to programmatically evaluate EL in a managed bean

Tags: jsf, el, templating

I would like to add a simple template language to my application based on Seam / JSF to let the users compose their own email.

Since I don't want to create a new parser, I would like to use the Unified Expression Language   setting the context all by myself.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're sitting inside the JSF context, then just use [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) to programmatically evaluate a string containing EL expressions.

```
String unevaluatedString = convertMailTemplateToStringSomehow();
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String evaluatedString = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, unevaluatedString, String.class);
// ...
```

If you're not sitting inside the JSF context, then you'd need to use a standalone EL API, such as [JUEL](http://juel.sourceforge.net/guide/start.html). Or, if you're already on EL 3.0 and the string represents the sole EL expression, then use the [`ELProcessor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELProcessor.html) API.

```
ELProcessor el = new ELProcessor();
el.defineBean("bean", new Bean());
el.eval("bean.foo"); // Without starting #{ and ending } !
// ...
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use the seam context? So that I DI object in the template. Something like http://blog.chintoju.com/2011/02/evaluate-an-el-expression.html

Comment: Seam has a simple way of evaluating templates with embedded EL expressions: `Interpolator.instance().interpolate()` method takes a string and interpolates any EL expressions it contains. Additionally, it can also interpolate up to 10 parameters you pass into the interpolator: `Interpolator.instance().interpolate("{0}#{' '}{1}", "foo", "bar");` returns `foo bar`.